# What push service do browsers use when sending push notifications between the request and the client?

Tags: push-notification, microsoft-edge

When using service workers to send push notifications to a user device from the Edge browser, does Edge use an Azure service as the push service to relay the message payload to the client?

I am interested in using push notifications inside a closed environment and confused on the security concerns I may need to be aware of.

Resources: [Push Service Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/how-push-works#who_and_what_is_the_push_service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc you provide, it says

> Each browser can use any push service they want, it's something developers have no control over. This isn't a problem because every push service expects the same API call. Meaning you don't have to care who the push service is. You just need to make sure that your API call is valid.

So I think you don't need to care about the push services browsers using and don't need to worry about the security concerns.

But to answer your question: For the push service Edge using, I think it's [Windows Push Notification Service (WNS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview). For other browsers, you can also refer to [this article](https://webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net/#appendix).